Arduino IDE Variable memory %180 ( when reference an element of a const char* list[] ( array of 30 texts }
This is the code, using Arduino IDE, simple sketch trying to print all the different texts from a const char* array of 300 different texts.
What am I doing wrong?
how can I print one by one using a loop, but using a dynamic reference to the array, brings the whole array to the variable memory and the compiler fails saying: Global variables use 3692 bytes (180%), Maximum is 2048 bytes.
But when I hard code just one, using for example index 50 of the array, it works fine, with a minimal amount of memory.  I'm sure there has to be a way to bring one by one.
This is the code:
const char* program[] = {
 "MyValue001","MyValue002","MyValue003","MyValue004","MyValue005","MyValue006","MyValue007","MyValue008","MyValue009","MyValue010"
,"MyValue011","MyValue012","MyValue013","MyValue014","MyValue015","MyValue016","MyValue017","MyValue018","MyValue019","MyValue020"
,"MyValue021","MyValue022","MyValue023","MyValue024","MyValue025","MyValue026","MyValue027","MyValue028","MyValue029","MyValue030",
 . . . .
 . . . .    // A total of 300 different texts 
 . . . .
,"MyValue281","MyValue282","MyValue283","MyValue284","MyValue285","MyValue286","MyValue287","MyValue288","MyValue289","MyValue290"
,"MyValue291","MyValue292","MyValue293","MyValue294","MyValue295","MyValue296","MyValue297","MyValue298","MyValue299","MyValue300"
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for (int i=0; i<256; i++) {

    Serial.print(program[50]);  // with this Arduino IDE compiles fine

    Serial.print(program[i]);   // with this Arduino IDE ran out of Memory for variables (2048

  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}

THIS IS THE ERROR when compiler fails running out of memory 180% using --> Serial.print(program[i]);
Sketch uses 4992 bytes (16%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 3692 bytes (180%) of dynamic memory, leaving -1644 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
Not enough memory; see https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360013825179 for tips on reducing your footprint.
data section exceeds available space in board
Compilation error: data section exceeds available space in board
THIS IS THE COMPLETION MESSAGE OK the compiler only uses 8% of variable memory
Sketch uses 1438 bytes (4%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 184 bytes (8%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1864 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
I want to have 300 different text on a char array, 14 character long max each. Let's call this a list of  Programs or Patches, like programs on a Synth keyboard, and depending on values enter by a Rotary Encoder, just print the name of the program selected on a LCD Display.
The example I select (above) is more basic than my original project, but fixing the issue on this code will help me to understand and easily adapt the solution to my main project
